# Code compiles with std::string even when the syntax appears bad and contains multiple '+' operator

Tags: c++, string, syntax, operator-overloading, language-lawyer

Why [this code](http://ideone.com/U60LPP) compiles without any error?

```
std::string s = std::string("Look at plus plus... ") + + "... Strange!\n";
```

Is it a standard code or generosity of g++ (v4.9)?

In fact y'day I had seen a crash happening which was pointing to `std::string` in the same region of code where these "wrong syntax" was present. Possibly this could be the culprit.

Comment: You are using unary `+` on a string literal, which decays it to a pointer.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a9fbb3154aac702